# Select option with jQuery based on HTML lang

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I have a multilang page with order form and I try to add some feature to auto-select country from `<select>` list based on language.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<select name="billing_country" id="billing_country" class="country_to_state country_select select2-hidden-accessible" autocomplete="country" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="">Land/Region auswählen&nbsp;…</option>
    <option value="CZ" selected="selected">Tschechien</option>
    <option value="FR">Frankreich</option>
    <option value="ES">Spanien</option>
    <option value="DE">Deutschland</option>
    <option value="IT">Italien</option>
</select>
```

And the page language inside the HTML attribute. In this case I would like to select option: `value="DE"`:

```
<html lang="de-DE" class="js svg background-fixed">
```

This is the only one language variable that I can use.

I need to target `<option>` value based on HTML `lang` attribute.

I think it can be done with jQuery. How to do it?

Comment: if you think one of the answeres were helpful, mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

- When the site is loaded then get the value of the lang of your site.
- Get all your options and iterate over it.
- Check if your sites value is included in the values of your list when yes then set the select attribute of this option to true.

```js
window.onload = myfunction;

function myfunction() {
  let initialLang = $("html")[0].lang;
  var myOpts = $('option');
  
  for(let i = 0; i < myOpts.length; i++){
  if(initialLang.includes(myOpts[i].value)){
   myOpts[i].selected = true;
  }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="de-DE" class="js svg background-fixed">

<select name="billing_country" id="billing_country" class="country_to_state country_select select2-hidden-accessible" autocomplete="country" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="">Land/Region auswählen&nbsp;…</option>
  <option value="CZ" selected="selected">Tschechien</option>
  <option value="FR">Frankreich</option>
  <option value="ES">Spanien</option>
  <option value="DE">Deutschland</option>
  <option value="IT">Italien</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Actually I need to select correct ```<option>``` when page is loaded. Script has to check the HTML lang if = ```de-DE``` then it must select ```<option value="DE">``` when I change the language for example to Spanish and page is refreshed, then html lang = ```es-ES``` and script must choose ```<option value ="ES">```.

Comment: have updated my answer @Mike 
I cannot use forEach or jquery .each so iterated old fashioned

Answer (score 0):

You can get html lang attribute using jquery [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) ,then use [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) to set select value :

Check this snippet below :

```js
$(function(){
    var htmlLang = $("html").attr("lang") || "cz-CZ" // default value if non present ;
    var lang = htmlLang.split("-")[1];
    
    console.log(lang);
    
    $("#billing_country").val(lang);
    
})
```

```html
<html lang="de-DE" class="js svg background-fixed">
<body>
<select name="billing_country" id="billing_country" class="country_to_state country_select select2-hidden-accessible" autocomplete="country" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="">Land/Region auswählen&nbsp;…</option>
  <option value="CZ" selected="selected" >Tschechien</option>
  <option value="FR">Frankreich</option>
  <option value="ES">Spanien</option>
  <option value="DE">Deutschland</option>
  <option value="IT">Italien</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't work. I change the language, then page is reloading and after refresh I still see the same option selected.

Comment: @Mike check in console if there are some errors so print them here ? also have added jquery cdn link ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const lang = $("html").attr("lang").split("-")[1];
$("#billing_country option").removeAttr("selected");
$("option[value="+ lang +"]").attr("selected", true);
```